# Why do the parameters (beta) blow up in LMS with Kernel Trick?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, least-squares

I am attempting to solve an LMS problem using kernel trick. The reference is taken from [this](http://cs229.stanford.edu/summer2020/cs229-notes3.pdf) note.

My problem is that the value of beta blows up. It reaches to the order of 10e17 on just about 5 or 6 iterations. One thing I noticed is that the signs entries in beta oscillate (positive to negative and vice versa) on consecutive update of beta in the loop.

Also, lowering the value of alpha (learning rate) does not help. I tried `alpha = 0.01` but the value of beta still blows up.
Here's the code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv("weatherHistory.csv")

#selecting only the required columns
useful_index = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
file = file.iloc[:, useful_index]

# getting training set and test set
file_randomized = file.sample(frac=1, random_state=1)

# useable data size
usable_dataset_size = 1200

# training set size
training_set_index = int(0.75 * usable_dataset_size)

# get rid of unnecessary data
file = file_randomized[:usable_dataset_size]

# make training and test set
training_set = file[:training_set_index]
test_set = file[training_set_index:]

# Select the columns
input_index = [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
X = training_set.iloc[:, input_index]
output_index = [1]
Y = training_set.iloc[:, output_index]

# Convert to numpy into suitable format
X = X.to_numpy()
n = X.shape[0]
d = X.shape[1]
Y = Y.to_numpy()

# This function calculates K(phi(x), phi(y))

def kernel_matrix(K, degree=1):
    """K is the matrix of dot product. This applies kernel function to the matrix"""
    result = np.zeros(K.shape)
    for i in range(0, degree+1):
        result += np.power(K, i)
    return result

# Main training function
def lms_with_kt(X, Y, alpha, degree = 1, num_iters = 1000):
    """X: nxd vector, Y: nx1 vector, beta: nx1 zero vector, alpha: number, degree: number"""
    # normalize x
    x_min = X.min(axis = 0, keepdims=True)
    x_max = X.max(axis = 0, keepdims=True)
    X = (X - x_min) / (x_max - x_min)
    n = X.shape[0]
    
    # add the column of 1 in the front
    X = np.hstack((np.ones((n, 1)), X))
    
    # make K_matrix (kernel matrix)
    K = np.matmul(X, X.T)
    K = kernel_matrix(K, degree)
    # initialize beta
    beta = np.zeros((n, 1))

    # update beta
    for i in range(num_iters):
        beta += alpha * (Y - np.matmul(K, beta))
    print(beta)
        
    def predict(x):
        """x: 1xd matrix"""
        x_norm = (x - x_min) / (x_max - x_min)
        n_predict = x_norm.shape[0]
        x_norm = np.hstack((np.ones((n_predict, 1)), x_norm))
        K_for_prediction = np.matmul(X, x_norm.T)
        K_for_prediction = kernel_matrix(K_for_prediction, degree)
        return np.dot(beta.T, K_for_prediction)

    return predict

predictor = lms_with_kt(X, Y, 0.1, 2, 1000)
```

The link to the dataset is [here](https://www.kaggle.com/budincsevity/szeged-weather).

Comment: Please add a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with an **example of your expected output** so that we can help you more.

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: @jajamaharaja no, I quit and became a backend developer.